# XML nodes printed twice

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

below is my code:

```
function widget_itemAddCallback(carousel, first, last, xml)
{   
    jQuery('image', xml).each(function(i){  
        document.write(jQuery('url',xml).text())
    });
...
};
```

This loops trough an XML file i send to the function. The XML file is build up like this:

```
<image>
   <url>URL1 HERE</url>
   <id>ID1 HERE</id>
</image>
<image>
   <url>URL2 HERE</url>
   <id>ID2 HERE</id>
</image>
```

now when I run trough that piece of code I posted above, the url's will be posted twice each (4 urls in total, should be 2). So for every loop trough an 'image' tag it will post all the url tags it can find in the XML under an image node. I can't seem to find how to make sure it only prints the url from the current node. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: your data structure is ok. just wrap it in <foo></foo> and it is valid ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('url',xml).text()
```

selects all url nodes- so you write all url nodes for all image nodes.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('url',xml)` will select all `url` elements in the document.

Since your iterating over the image elements, you only want the `url` element of the current image, which is accessible via `this`:

```
jQuery(this).find('url').text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/62H8Z/1/)

Comment: Thanks guys, I did it a bit like felix said. This is what I came up with for extracting the url of the current image node i was in:

var url = $(this).children('url').text();

This would give me the url of the current image tag!